# Am doing the destructing right?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a coding challenge, which am sure am getting it right , but the challenge requires that certain steps need to be in account before moving forward. And i seem to be skipping a step which is to de-structure a value from a target of an event(hope am saying it right)

The question is to get the expected event parameter to the target property with a de-structure.

Is my code wrong?

```
const displaySelectedUser = (event) => {
    var newcal = event.target.value;

    console.log(newcal);
    console.log((event.target.value));

    var user = getSelectedUser(newcal);

    var properties = Object.keys(user);

    console.log(properties);

    properties.forEach(prop => {
        const span = document.querySelector(`span[data-${prop}-value]`);

        if (span) {
            span.innerText = user[prop];
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not wrong - but the only practical opportunity you have for destructuring is here:

```
var newcal = event.target.value;
```

Do this:

```
var { target: { value: newcal } } = event;
```

Because you're not using the other properties of `event`, you could move this up to the function declaration instead:

```
const displaySelectedUser = ({ target: { value: newcal } }) => {...}
```

Now `newcal` will already be defined as `event.target.value` in your function.

Comment: Hi jack, it doesnt seem to work or am probably not doing it right could you please elaborate

Comment: If the code you posted works, then this will also work - I changed nothing, just used destructuring for the declaration of `newcal`.